# Ruby backup Gem s3 upload not working

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, backup

I am testing the backup gem and the size of the db is very small. I have mongodb with me.

My configuration is:

```
Backup::Model.new(:backup_db, 'Backup for my db') do
  split_into_chunks_of 250
  database MongoDB do |db|
   db.name               = "my_dev"
   # db.username           = ""
   # db.password           = ""
   db.host               = "localhost"
   db.port               = 27017
   db.ipv6               = false
   # db.only_collections   = ["only", "these", "collections"]
   db.additional_options = []
   db.lock               = false
   db.oplog              = false
 end

 store_with S3 do |s3|
   s3.access_key_id     = "my key"
   s3.secret_access_key = "my key"
   s3.region            = "my region"
   s3.bucket            = "https://region-2.amazonaws.com/bucket-name"
   s3.keep              = 10
   s3.max_retries = 3
   s3.retry_waitsec = 5
   s3.chunk_size = 5 # MiB
 end
 sync_with Cloud::S3 do |s3|
   s3.access_key_id     = "my key"
   s3.secret_access_key = "my key"
   s3.bucket            = "https://region-2.amazonaws.com/bucket-name"
   s3.region            = "my-region"
   # s3.path              = ""
   s3.mirror            = true
   s3.concurrency_type  = false
   s3.concurrency_level = 2

   s3.directories do |directory|
   end
 end 

 compress_with Gzip
end
```

When running backup perform, I am getting the following error:

```
[2017/05/30 14:23:28][error] ModelError: Backup for Backup Gauge Lrs db (backup_db) Failed!
[2017/05/30 14:23:28][error]   An Error occured which has caused this Backup to abort before completion.
[2017/05/30 14:23:28][error]   Reason: Excon::Errors::SocketError
[2017/05/30 14:23:28][error]   break from proc-closure (LocalJumpError)
[2017/05/30 14:23:28][error]
[2017/05/30 14:23:28][error] Backtrace:
```

Anyone explain me about this error? I run the command with the log file option. Same log I am getting in the file too.

I am using Rails 4.2 and Ruby 2.2.1

Backup Gem version is 3.4.0

Answer (score 0):

I reconfigured the backup setup and now it is working fine. I don't know why this error came before.

I used the following command to run the backup:

```
$ backup perform --trigger my_backup
```

The steps that I taken to get it work:

1. I am using rbenv, I created .ruby-gemset and .ruby-version in a new folder and installed backup

   ```
   $ gem install backup
   ```

It installed all the dependencies of backup.

2. Generated the model with my mongodb

   ```
   $ backup generate:model --trigger my_backup --storages='s3' --compressor='gzip' --notifiers='mail'  --databases="mongodb"
   ```
3. And run the backup perform command, it works!

   ```
   $ backup perform --trigger my_backup
   ```

:)